# Access Spring Context in test class

Tags: java, spring, testing

Why the following test fails?

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringContextTest{

    @Autowired
    House house;
    
    @Test
    void houseBeanShouldNotBeNull(){
        assertThat(house).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class House {}
```

If I understood this correctly `@SpringBootTest` initializes the spring context, therefore it should instantiate the `House` bean and add it to the context.

So I thought the problem was due to the packages and classes scanned when looking for beans, so I've tried:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {House.class})
```

but the test still fails... what am i missing?

spring: 4.3.6
spring-boot: 1.5.1
junit: 5.10.1
java: 8

Comment: The version of Spring Boot you're using (1.5.1) and Spring Framework (4.3.6) are relatively old, and you're using JUnit 5.10.1, which is much newer. There's a potential compatibility issue here since Spring Boot 1.5.x primarily supports JUnit 4 out of the box. I'd try upgrading to recent version first

Answer (score 0):

Missing @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringContextTest{

    @Autowired
    House house;
    
    @Test
    void houseBeanShouldNotBeNull(){
        assertThat(house).isNotNull();
    }
}
```